# How to update a relationship when another field is modified in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a simple `Client` model in SQLAlchemy, using mostly declarative. This model has a `name` field and has a many-to-many relationship with a `MetaphoneCode` model. The code goes like this:

```
class MetaphoneCode(Base):
    """Represents a metaphone code
    """
    __tablename__ = 'mcodes'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('mcodes_seq_id'), primary_key=True)
    code = Column(String(20), index=True, nullable=False)


client_mcode_assoc_table = Table(
    'client_mcodes',
    Base.metadata,
    Column('client_id', ForeignKey('clients.id')),
    Column('mcode_id', ForeignKey('mcodes.id')))


class Client(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'clients'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('client_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode(100), index=True)
    mcodes = relationship('MetaphoneCode', secondary=client_mcode_assoc_table)
```

Now, since metaphone codes must change when the `name` itself change, I'd like to express this need so that when I do `client.name = "John Doe"` I would like to calculate the metaphone codes relate to those names (first and last names) and have the `mcodes` relationship updated.

**Update**: I have found a simple solution as quoted [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970757/how-to-update-a-relationship-when-another-field-is-modified-in-sqlalchemy#answer-16985582); so my questions is best stated as "*Is the ORM Attributes Event system the best-practice mechanism to update an attribute in response of the change of another one?*"

Comment: Why you do not want do pass through the InstrumentedAttribute ?

Comment: @ScotchAndSoda I don't want to avoid InstrumentedAttributed, is just that I would create a sub-class that on its `__set__` method would call some callback. But that's not really needed since SQLAlchemy already has the `@event.listens_for` which is practically the same I would accomplish by hacking InstrutementedAttribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to do it by using events:

```
@event.listens_for(Client.name, 'set')
def update_mcodes(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
    target.recalculate_mcodes(value)
```

Still, is this the recommended way to do this? I will read the Hybrid approach suggested by @Xaqq and decide if that is better than this `event` stuff.

Comment: Didnt know about event, might be better than hybrid property. Of course, would be great if some experienced user gives us infos :D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using getter and setter would allow to fix you problem.

SqlAlchemy provides a way to add getter and setter to your model's attribute. I've never used them myself. See http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/extensions/hybrid.html.

However I can't tell if it's good pratice to run business logic code inside those setter. Maybe someone more experienced will tell us.

Comment: @Xaqq, @ScotchAndSoda : I don't really see how hybrid attributes match my use case. It seems that I would have to define a `fullname` `@hybrid_property` with a setter. But then I would have to change all my code to set the `fullname` instead of `name`. Or I would have to change the column `name` to e.g `_name` and then define `name` as a hybrid property. Neither way seem right.

Comment: @manu I suppose the second way is the way to go with hybrid property (as far as i understand)

Comment: I have been reading extensively the Hybrids docs. I thinks it is suitable for other use cases, thought. I'm marking my answer then. But I'm already using hybrids in my code for other purposes, so thanks for the pointer.